# Items in Canvas mismatching their calculated positions due to dpi difference in image XAML

Tags: image, xaml, canvas, dpi

I was having a problem trying to put a square in a correct position of the Canvas, that contains Image (receiving from API as byte[]). Some rectangles were displayed corectly, some where somewhat off and some where completely off and not even close to where it should be.

```
<Viewbox>
        <Canvas Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=img}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=img}">
            <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding Image.Image, ElementName=uc}" Stretch="None" />
            <Rectangle Canvas.Left="{Binding Image.ImageAttributes.Rect.X, ElementName=uc}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Image.ImageAttributes.Rect.Y, ElementName=uc}" Visibility="{Binding ShowBox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter} }" Width="{Binding Image.ImageAttributes.Rect.Width, ElementName=uc}" Height="{Binding Image.ImageAttributes.Rect.Height, ElementName=uc}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
                <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Image.ImageAttributes.Roll, ElementName=uc}"/>
                </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
```

At first I thought it might be because I was getting wrong data values from the API or there was a problem with back-end. After more than a day of debugging I finally figured it out, that it was due to DPI in images. For example:
lets say normally some image dimensions were 300 x 450, but in xaml the actualHeight/actualWidth are set as 400x600. That's because the dpi of the image was 72 and default dpi in xaml seems to be 96 (300 / 72 * 96 = 400). But the Rectangle doesn't take into account the fact that image Dimensions changed and is drawn where it should have been (eg. absolute values from DB are: X:30, Y:45, Height:90, Width:90 now should be drawn in X:40, Y:60, Height:120, Width:120 to be correct) after dimension change.

My question would be: Is there any way to normalize the dpi before displaying the image or normalizing it before sending it to the API to be processed and added into the DB?
If not, how could I resize or get the dpi difference to calculate the new values for other items in Canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning to not leave the question unanswered. Here is the solution:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
    <Canvas Name="cnvImage" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=img}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=img}">
        <Image Name="img" Width="{Binding Source.PixelWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Height="{Binding Source.PixelHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Source="{Binding NImage, ElementName=uc}"/>
    </Canvas>
        <Canvas Name="grAttribute" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=cnvImage}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=cnvImage}">
    </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

No need to reavaluate or recalculate anything.
To make this work you need to assign
`Width="{Binding Source.PixelWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Height="{Binding Source.PixelHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

Also, I splited the creation of rectangle to my wpf, so I have 2 canvas's now, but it's unrelated to the question.